vscode bash commandline on Windows: fatal: unable to access 'C:\Users?serABC/.config/git/config' : Invalid argument
I am developing a Python Django api and I have struggled with auto activating my virtual environment for my repo. I have had to manually initialize it. I restarted my visual studio code and when I reopened I noticed that the virtual enironment activates now. This may or may not be due to a VSCode update.
I noticed that on VSCode bash commandline the location listed is C:/Users/userABC/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code. When I run pwd the correct directory prints.  This would be fine, but the commandline no longer lists the git branch for my repo. When I tried to get a list of branches with git branch -a, I get the following error: fatal: unable to access 'C:\Users?serABC/.config/git/config': Invalid argument where userABC is my login name. How do I fix this? Did a configuration file get corrupted?

Looks like something interpreted \u in your string as the start of a unicode sequence.

After VS Code was update in April 2024, this also happened on my home PS, but on my laptop is OK.
That helped me:

Open terminal: Win + R, write sysdm.cpl and press Enter
In the "Advanced" tab, click the "Environment variables" button
In the section "User environment variables for UserABC", click the "Create" button and create a variable with the name "HOME" and the value "C\Users\UserABC"
Save and restart the computer.


What worked for me was:

Go to vscode and open a Git Bash Terminal

cd /c/Users/UserABC

nano .bashrc

Add the following at the end of the file:
export HOME="c/Users/UserABC"
cd $HOME
Save the file and exit

source .bashrc


After that I was able to access to my repo using Git

The last comment helped me, but the value of the HOME variable should be C:\Users\UserABC, and using a colon after the C.
